# academic subjects that you read and memorize vs. those including math and formulas

Tags: word-request

Are there inclusive terms to describe academic subjects that requires reading and memorizing such as literature and those requiring math  and problem solving such as math and physics_ maybe something like reading subjects and problem-solving ones?

> A: Hey Alan, how do you manage to prepare for the exam season like that and you still have some time to spare with your friends?!
>
> B: Well, I leave the [**memorizing**] subjects to what I can keep in mind over the exam night and get practice on the [**problem-solving**] ones during the term.

Comment: **problem-solving**, not "problems-solving".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One related word that comes to my mind is ***rote***.

When something is learned through memorization, we say that it is learned *by rote*. From NOAD:

> **rote** (*noun*) mechanical or habitual repetition of something to be learned: *a poem learned by rote in childhood*.

In education, another related term is [***Bloom’s Taxonomy***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom%27s_taxonomy), which is a six-layered hierarchy of ways learning can be evaluated and demonstrated. Regarding your question, an educator might say that some courses are at the **Remembering** level of Bloom’s (or **Knowledge** level), while others are at the **Applied** level. (That said, a room full of English professors might bristle at your characterization, insisting that their goal is to teach at even *higher* levels of Bloom’s, such as Analyzing and Evaluating!)

For further reading about Bloom’s, you can view [this page](https://cft.vanderbilt.edu/guides-sub-pages/blooms-taxonomy/) from Vanderbilt University’s Center for Teaching.

So, going back to the dialog in your question, it could go like this:

> A: Hey Alan, how do you manage to prepare for the exam season like that and you still have some time to spare with your friends?!
>
> B: Well, I leave the **more rote** subjects to what I can keep in mind over the exam night and get practice on the **more applied** ones during the term.

That said, Bloom’s is more widely known in professional education circles than among the general public, so I’m not sure students would realistically use the term “applied” in that way. The word “rote,” however, is more generally known.

Comment: Taking that _applied_ is not much of a common word, you might be suggesting I say something like _less rote_ instead of applied. Is that so?

Comment: @ Yuri - I would use _applied_ before I would use _less rote_.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know if we have a label for academic subjects where only short-term memory is required to succeed and a label for subjects where problem-solving skills are required.

American college students call particular *courses* (not subjects or areas of study) **gut courses** if students can get by only by reading and regurgitating what they've read.

I don't know of a term for classes that require mastery of the subject matter.

Comment: The complement to a “gut” course might be a “real” course?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the possible and also common labels which students use to call these. My first guess was _easy_ and _difficult_ though it might not be the case for everyone. History might be a piece of cake for one while a real pain in the neck for another. I really wonder how English speakers would refer to these concepts. **If you were Alan, how would you say that?**

Comment: As I said, I would only refer to a particular *course* in that way, not to any subject.